# При первом клике блоки должны появляться, при следующем пропадать

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class='container' data-title="Hello!"></div>
<div class='boxes box1'>Glad to see you there!</div>
<div class='boxes box2'>What is your name?</div>
<div class='boxes box3'>What do you like?</div>
<div class='boxes box4'>Tell me :)</div>
```

JQuery подключен. Прошу помощи )

```
     $( window ).load(function() {
  document.$('.container').click(function() {
    var boxes = $('.boxes');  
    if(boxes.hasClass('showed')){          
      boxes.style.display = 'none';
      boxes.removeClass('showed');    
    }
     else {             
      boxes.style.display = 'flex'; 
      boxes.addClass('showed');      
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: если jquery  подключен, то к чему вот эта вся фигня на ванильном js?

Comment: Прошу прощения, уже изменил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

может так:

```js
     
 $(document).on('click', '.container', function() {
    var boxes = $('.boxes');  
    var state = $(this).data('state');     
    state = !state; 
    
    if (state)
      boxes.addClass('showed');
    else
      boxes.removeClass('showed');    

     $(this).data('state', state);  
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  display: none;
}

.showed {
  color: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container' data-title="Hello!" data-state="false">click</div>
<div class='boxes box1'>Glad to see you there!</div>
<div class='boxes box2'>What is your name?</div>
<div class='boxes box3'>What do you like?</div>
<div class='boxes box4'>Tell me :)</div>
```

Манипуляция только классами. Ну и дополнительная `data-state`, чтоб знать текущее состояние элементов

Answer (score 2):

Все как у @АлексейШиманский, только:

```
$(document).on('click', '.container', function() {
  $('.boxes').toggleClass('showed');  
});
```

Comment: Кстати да. Правда я в начале тоже `toggleClass` писал. Потом увидел, что есть `show/hide` (помимо `color: red`) и подумал, что там могут наверное быть еще какие-либо обработчики помимо стилевых и решил переделать)